# Run a JAVA main method from maven when there are file changes

Tags: java, maven

I have configured a maven `pom.xml` with `exec-maven-plugin` to execute a JAVA main method, however, it is always executed on both `mvn install` and `mvn clean install`.

Are there alternatives/configuration changes/ to execute a JAVA main method only if there are any changes to the project. The project is being checked out from a SVN repository.

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>code-generator</id>
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
     <executions>
      <execution>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.package.TestClass</mainClass>
        <arguments>
         <argument>test</argument>
        </arguments>
       </configuration>
      </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting a CHANGE is not easy, even maven itself has [quite an issue](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-209) with it. Unless you write your own maven plugin (which is quite possible nowadays) you're basically stuck to executing your file everytime you build the approproate step.

A workaround might be building only **specific goals** - you can execute `maven compile`, for example - that way you wont (!) execute `package` hence your java-file wont get executed.

For more info [read this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

What would work is to create a [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task to watch for changes and then have a task run these maven commands [when a change occurs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch).

The only problem is you'd have to learn grunt and run it separately.  But, *it would work*.

Have grunt execute a profile with the "exec-maven-plugin", otherwise, you don't use that profile.

Comment: Grunt is for JavaSCRIPT - he was asking about Java. Two completely different worlds. One may use grunt-exec and do all of the complex compile-stuff yourself via vast amounts of commandline-parameters but that'd be extremely inefficient AND error-prone.

Comment: @specializt I'm aware.  He could have the grunt task run `mvn install`.  I don't think it'd be inefficient or error-prone.  Just unusual.  Plus, because it *would* work, it's currently a better answer than yours, IMHO.

Comment: solely running maven via commandline and without necessary (!) environment-changes which are done by your IDE _WILL_ get you into loads of trouble, thats guaranteed. Its the main reason for eclipse being so popular : it does all the background-work.
Hence : that'd be inefficient, being inefficient in regards of working-time / task or simply computing-time / compile-command.

Comment: @specializt I don't use eclipse, but Intellij-IDEA doesn't care if I clean/install/whatever from the command line.  You don't know if he uses eclipse either, so that point seems irrelevant.

Comment: You have obviously not understood what i wrote.